# How to represent a Java property of X interface relation with said Interface in UML?

Tags: java, uml, modeling

In my Java class I have something along the lines of `private InterfaceName attributeName`, meaning that `attributeName` may have an object of any class that implements `InterfaceName`.

How could I represent this **relationship** in an UML class diagram? With a normal class, I've been explained of Aggregation, but I have doubts if this applies to interfaces too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, the type of the field is the interface. In your UML you should have something like

```
variableName : InterfaceName
```

This informs someone reading the UML diagram that this particular variable accepts objects that implement a particular interface.

Comment: Re-reading my own question, I think I failed to explain my question. I'm not interested in the class/interface itself, but the relation (Association, Aggregation, Composition...). Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I see.. Well, given that this is a field with the same lifetime and the same owner as the parent class, this would be an example of Composition. Even if it is an interface, the object's existence in your class is very concrete :) Does this answer your question?

Comment: From what I understand, Aggregation is when a Class has an Attribute of another, exterior Class and Composition when the Class referenced is inside/interior to the Class itself. Am I wrong here, maybe? Anyways, I think I've understood your explanation. Thanks. :)

Comment: Composition (a hollow diamond in uml) is an association relationship, where one class contains a reference to that class, and the class is created inside the other class. Ergo they have the same lifetimes, and the same owner. :)